# Not able to connect to SQL Server from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database, connection

I am currently working on an application server, and a SQL Server, in which my database resides.

I seem to have a very weird problem, I seem to be able to ping the SQL Server from my application server, but I cannot connect using SQL Server Management Studio using Windows authentication. If I try to change the password in configuration manager, I get an error saying that it is not possible.

I cannot connect to database, neither remote or locally..

SMSS - says that the login failed for the user.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Change the password of what? If you're using Windows Authentication then you don't need to enter a password. What do you mean by cannot connect? What's the error? Can you connect locally on the server? More details, please. :)

Comment: Do you mean change the SQL Server service account password? What is the exact error message when you try that? What is the error message when you try to connection from SSMS?

Comment: That's not SSMS there's, that's the password for the service. You need to find out what account the service should be running under, and get its password. I note, however, that the service says it's already running, so why are you trying to change the service account anyway?

Comment: I get the idea that you don't have SSMS Installed. You can download the latest version of SSMS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: I do have ssms installed...

Comment: That second image (the one you initially posted) isn't for SSMS, hence my comment. For the top image, if you can't login, and it's a Windows login, I'd hazard a guess that you haven't had a login created on your server. You'll need to ask the DBA to create one for you. Just because you have windows logon for your domain doesn't mean you can connect to any and all of the SQL Server instances on your server. In fact, you can't connect to any until the DBA configures your login, or one for an AD group you're a member of.